# How to pass id using Link in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, router

i have create a simple website.I have to create two pages first page is to show various catergories. Second page is to details. for example images, description also. i have click link to pass data from second page but still now i have error can not pass data. Error:

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'fetchiditem'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

How to solve my error please give me solution.

> App.js

```
<Routes>
  <Route path='/shop' exact element={<Shop />}></Route>
  <Route path='/shop/:id' element={<Shopdetails />}></Route>
</Routes>
```

> Shop.js

```
 function Shop() {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchitems();
  }, []);

  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const fetchitems = async () => {
    const data = await fetch("https://fortnite-api.theapinetwork.com/upcoming/get"
);
    const itemsdata = await data.json();
   // console.log(itemsdata.data);
    setItems(itemsdata.data);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {items.map(item => (
        <h1 key={item.itemId}>
        <Link to={`/shop/${item.itemId}`}>{item.item.name}</Link>
        </h1>
      ))}
    </div>
  );

}

export default Shop;
```

> Shopdetails.js

```
    function Shopdetails({match}) {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchiditem();
  }, []);
  const [itemid, setitems] = useState([]);
 
  console.log(match);

  const fetchiditem = async () => {
    const data = await fetch (`https://fortnite-api.theapinetwork.com/item/get?id=${match.params.id}`
    );
    const itemdata = await data.json();
    setitems(itemdata.data.item);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <img src={itemid.images.icon} alt="" />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Shopdetails;
```

Comment: The error message tells you what the problem is and gives you two options for solving it, what's unclear?

Comment: i pass id shop screen to shop details screen. how to get id shop details screen

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the `fetchiditem` in the array:

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetchiditem();
}, [fetchiditem]);
```

Comment: Line 7:7:   'fetchiditem' was used before it was defined

Comment: Move the const declaration above the useEffect.

Comment: above error ,  what i do

Comment: i can't understand

Comment: Which declaration move to above.?

Comment: You have to define the const before you can use it. Call the `const fetchiditem =` part before the `useEffect` part.

Comment: i was try but not working

Comment: can you please give full code

Comment: I recommend you revisit (or learn to begin with) the basics of JavaScript and React. The errors you see are basic fundamental errors that describe what the issues are. You're not gong to be able to work with React components and hooks if even the basics don't make sense to you and you're probably jumping in the deep end before you can swim.

Comment: ok dude. i have to learn , because should i ask any doubt no one is here so only asking this site.

Answer (score 0):

Define the function inside the `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchiditem = async () => {
        const data = await fetch(
            `https://fortnite-api.theapinetwork.com/item/get?id=${match.params.id}`
        );
        const itemdata = await data.json();
        setitems(itemdata.data.item);
    };

    fetchiditem();
}, [match.params.id]);
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')

Comment: I have above error .